# To find resistance of wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-current

How to find resistance of wire $\displaystyle{R=\rho\frac{ L}{A}}$
if diameter of wire is doubled?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Hint: try writing the wire area $A$ as a function of the wire diameter ...